# Recommended resources for learning database development with Cocoa?

Tags: database, cocoa, oracle, reference, sybase

I am currently learning Cocoa.  However I am coming from a traditional Sybase/Oracle background using Powerbuilder.  Having been spoiled by the 'power' of a datawindow for may years, I not sure that coredata or sqllite will satisfy my needs and ideas.
Basically I'm looking for some good reference sites, books, or just plain old advice on how to approach database development with Cocoa.
Any comments and advice are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty broad topic, but if you want to go down the Core Data route, check out this book http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data
Core Data published by Pragmatic.

Core Data is a persistence solution that is highly object oriented and integrated with cocoa.  In my opinion it is relatively easy to implement basic persistence with it.

Marcus Zarra, the author of the book I recommended also has a great Cocoa blog with lots of Core Data resources: http://www.cimgf.com/category/core-data/